# Weka - Construct Instances Object

Tags: java, weka

I'm trying to create an `Instances` object in my java code. According to the [javadoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#Instances%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList,%20int%29), an `Instances` can be constructed as:

```
public Instances(java.lang.String name,
                 java.util.ArrayList<Attribute> attInfo,
                 int capacity)
```

In my code, I have the following:

```
ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
Instances trainingData = new Instances("TestRelation",attributes,0);
```

However, this throws the error (in Eclipse): `The constructor Instances(String, ArrayList<Attribute>, int) is undefined`

Could someone tell me how to correct this?

**EDIT:**
I downloaded the developer version of weka, v.3-7-10, and that seems to have cleared up the issue. But I'd prefer to use the stale release, v.3-6-10.

Comment: In eclipse, type new Instances(  then CTRL+space. Eclipse will show you the available constructors. Also, check that in Instances ans Attribute classes imported in your class are the ones from Weka and not another lib.

Comment: Thanks. I checked, and this constructor is not available. I don't know why it's not being recognized. The `Instances` and `Attribute` objects were imported correctly.

Comment: Specifically, it's looking for a `Fastvector`, which was deprecated a while ago.